# sum of xor values of all pairs

Tags: algorithm, xor

We have an array `A (say [1,2,3])` . We need to find the ***XOR(^)SUM*** of all pairs of integers in the array. 
Though this can easily be done in `O(n^2)` but how can i improve the complexity of the solution ?
E.g for the above array , A, the answer would be `(1^2)+(1^3)+(2^3) = 6`
Thanks.

Comment: By "sum" I am assuming you mean bitwise or.

Comment: NO. Xor all the distinct pairs and calculate the sum of all these values.

Comment: In that case I get `1^2+1^3+2^3 = 3 + 2 + 1 = 6`.

Comment: Thanks Matt..question updated.

Comment: What should the answer be for `[1,2,2]`? Is it `(1^2)+(1^2)=6`, or `1^2=3`? If it's the first, then it is unnecessary to specify "distinct pairs" in the question since `2^2=0` anyway and wouldn't contribute to the sum.

Comment: the answer would be 6 in that case

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can separate the calculation to do one bit at a time.

For example, look at the rightmost bit of all the numbers in the array. Suppose that `a` numbers have a rightmost 0-bit, and `b` numbers have a 1-bit. Then out of the pairs, `a*b` of them will have 1 in the rightmost bit of the XOR. This is because there are `a*b` ways to choose one number that has a 0-bit and one that has a 1-bit. These bits will therefore contribute `a*b` towards the total of all the XORs.

In general, when looking at the `n`th bit (where the rightmost bit is the 0th), count how many numbers have 0 (call this a<sub>n</sub>) and how many have 1 (call this b<sub>n</sub>). The contribution towards the final sum will be a<sub>n</sub>*b<sub>n</sub>*2<sup>n</sup>. You need to do this for each bit and sum all these contributions together.

This can be done in O(kn) time, where `k` is the number of bits in the given values.

Comment: Great idea Interjay! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Awesome idea. Thanks

Comment: how this condition is true for array [2,3], xor of 2 and 3 is 1, but the result gives 1+2=3.

Comment: @RaviSevta This would give 1*1*1 + 2*0*2 = 1 which is correct.

Comment: @interjay but for [1,2,3] result is 1*0*1 + 1*1*2 + 2*0*4=2

Comment: @RaviSevta It's 1*2*1 + 1*2*2 = 6. For each bit position, the sum of number of 1-bits and 0-bits must be 3 because there are 3 numbers in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jfx27/1/) confirming interjay's answer which does the calculation using both methods O(N^2) vs O(Nk):

```
var list = [1,2,2,3,4,5]

function xorsum_on2( a )
{
    var sum = 0
    for( var i=0 ; i<a.length ; ++i )
        for( var j=i+1 ; j<a.length ; ++j )
            sum += a[i]^a[j]
    return sum
}

// This sets all elements of a to 0
function xorsum_onk( a )
{
    var allzeroes;
    var sum = 0;
    var power = 0;
    do {
        allzeroes = true;
        var bitcount = [0,0];
        for( var i=0 ; i<a.length ; ++i )
        {
            bitcount[a[i]&1]++;
            a[i] >>= 1;
            if( a[i] ) allzeroes = false;
        }
        sum += (bitcount[0]*bitcount[1]) << power++;
    } while( !allzeroes );
    return sum;
}


var onk = document.getElementById("onk")
var on2 = document.getElementById("on2")

on2.innerHTML = xorsum_on2(list)
onk.innerHTML = xorsum_onk(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long int n,i,j,k;

    cin>>n; // number of elements in array 
    long long int arr[n],ans=0;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>arr[i];

    // iterate through all the bits
    for(i=0;i<32;i++)
    {
        k=0; // k is the number of set bits in the array at ith psotion
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            if((arr[j] & (1<<i)))
                k++;
        /* there are k set bits and n-k unset bits.
            therefore number of pairs with one set bit and one unset bit is kC1 and n-kC1
            Every pair adds 2^i in the answer.
        */
        ans+= (1<<i)*(k*(n-k));     
    }
    cout<<ans<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (What does this answer add? (IF [Matt's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21389715/3789665) contained the bitwise approach, only, I'd consider it marginal.))