# Sum Of Pairwise Anding

Tags: arrays, algorithm, bit-manipulation

We are given an array of size **N** and we have to  the calculate sum of **Ai** AND(&) **Aj** for all the pairs (i, j) where **i < j**.Size of array can be as large as **10^5**.So what is the best way to calculate.Better than **O(n^2)**.

Comment: What is the size of each array element: one bit? one integer?

Comment: each array element is <=10^9

Comment: OK - having thought about it this is very easy to do in O(n) - I'll write it up later when I have some time unless you've already worked it out for yourself.

Comment: Don't write it for me even if you have time.I want to do this myself.Can you give me the rough idea atleast so that i can think upon it.

Comment: @snehasharma I guess I'm confused about what you're asking. Do you want the answer, or just a hint?

Comment: Sure - just think about how you would do this for one bit in each element.

Comment: @templatetypedef i am just asking for hint.

Comment: Think about the property of distribution

Comment: Related to [sum of xor of all pairs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388448/sum-of-xor-values-of-all-pairs), but different. Not hard to adapt that answer though.

Comment: @harold yes,my question is quite similar to sum of xor of all pairs..This much hint will be sufficient..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. We can solve this problem for each bit independently.
2. For a fix bit `b`, let's call the number of elements that have this bit set to one `f(b)`.
3. The answer is `sum for all b f(b) * (f(b) - 1) / 2 * 2 ^ b`.

Why is it correct? Let's assume that `b` is fixed. The and of two numbers has this bit set to one if and only if both of this numbers have this bit set to one. If the number of elements that have this bit set is `f(b)`, there are exactly `f(b) * (f(b) - 1) / 2`  pairs such that both elements have this bit set. Now we can just find the sum for all `b`.