# xor of sum of all possible pairs from 2 arrays

Tags: c++

Hi I recently saw a post that was about finding sum of xor values of all pairs in an array but Im curios if you can imply this for 2 arrays meaning that for each pair (ai,bj) calculate ai+bj and the xor all this sums .
I would appreciate it if you give me any idea.
the post that is saw the problem in:
[sum of xor values of all pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388448/sum-of-xor-values-of-all-pairs)

Comment: my only idea was to itrate all possible pairs but I thought that was too obvious too say I wanted to find an efficient implementation because arrays can have upto 1e5 elements. @Scheff

Comment: no that is ok if you can maintain it with one loop (I mean o(n)) but you cannot find all possible pairs with one loop. @Scheff

Comment: Are you looking for any kind of clever re-ordering to re-use pre-computed intermediate results?

Comment: May be, it's worth to tag [tag:math] as well. If you are looking for "clever re-ordering", this is IMHO based on whether there can be exploited special relations between operators `^` and `+`. (Both are commutative but what else?) I googled a bit and found e.g. [Prove XOR is commutative and associative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/293793) not a solution at all but illustrates what I mean. Unfortunately, I'm a dummy concerning such mathematical things... ;-)

Comment: I don't get how re-ordering the arrays would help I mean you still have to itrate n*n pairs that would exceed the time limit.@Scheff

Comment: It's just an idea. A simple example: a * b + a * c could be rewritten as a * (b + c). Et voila, one multiply eliminated. However, I'm not sure how to do it for + and ^ but it might be possible...

Comment: I would say bit by bit, so for each power of 2, count number of bits at 1 in each array.