# Sum of special function in range

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, xor

i want to calculate sum of a function defined over [L, R].

The function first calculates xor of every substring of the number and then adds distinct values calculated and returns it.

```
Eg: F(312) 
    3 = 3
    3^1 = 2
    3^1^2 = 0
    1 = 1
    1^2 = 3
    2 = 2
    Sum of distinct values = 3+2+1 = 6 = F(312)
```

How can i calculate this fast? L, R can range from 1 to 1000000000.

Eg: if i give L = 5 and R = 15, then function should calculate F(5) + F(6) + F(7) ... + F(15)

Comment: Is there some programming language you intend to use? Also clarify: 3^1 in most languages means 3 powered by 1, that is 3. Why is 3^1 = 2 and 1^2 = 3?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone from the question's context it will be the XOR operator.

Comment: Ah ok, I got it rereading the question carefully. And is there a prefered language?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Yes as bashrc said, its the xor operator. also, i am interested behind the algorithm to solve this. so any language would work :)

Comment: Interesting question. How do you know what numbers to XOR with? E.g., I get why 3 (binary 11) would be XORed with (10, 01), because they are all smaller. But why is 1 in the input is XORed with 2 (10 bin), which is a bigger binary number, and not XORed with 32, say?

Comment: @SteveCooper Its xor of every continous substring. For example for a random string 2943, continous substring 2, 29, 294, 2943, 9, 94, 943, 4, 43, 3. Then the xor for each of this substring is calculated and the distinct elements are added in function F

Comment: OK, that makes sense.

Comment: The following thread should be interessting for you [Algorithm to add sum of every possible xor-sum sub-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113622/algorithm-to-add-sum-of-every-possible-xor-sum-sub-array)

Comment: @AyoubFalah - The linked riddle in that other question seems to be very similar, even the identifiers `F(L,R)`. However, they do not ask for F(5)+F(6)+..+F15), but F(array.slice(L, R)). Might this be a misinterpretation by Alex? Or is it a modified version of the old mystery?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone The problem stated here is a special case of the other described in the referred thread. That means, we can reuse a suggested correct solution to solve this problem. For instance, let L := 5, R := 15, so the size of the array a is: R - L + 1(The formula for computing the number of numbers in a given interval [L, R]), then we have to initialse the a with a[0] = 5, a[1] = 6, ..., a[10] = 15. Ultimately we can apply a correct solution suggested in the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution in JavaScript could look like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function sumXorSubStr(numStr)
{
  numStr = parseInt(numStr).toString();

  var
    results = {},
    lastPos = numStr.length -1
  ;

  for(var start=0 ; start <= lastPos ; start++)
    for(var op = 0, i = start ; i <= lastPos ; i++)
      results[ op ^= numStr[i] ] = 1;

  var sum = 0;
  for(var i in results)
    sum += parseInt(i);
  return sum;
}

alert( sumXorSubStr(312) );

</script>
```

A wrapper function to loop from/to is a suboptimal way. A little more performance can be reached by combining it in one function.

```
function sumRangeXorSubStr(from, to)
{
  var result = 0;

  for(var n=from; n<=to; n++)
    result += sumXorSubStr(n);

  return result;
}
```

I've some idea of a more performant way, not sure if I'll get it...

Comment: Thanks for this, however i wanted to calculate sum of this F function within a range [L, R]. as i see this code just calculates answer for a single number, i updated the question details to make it clear

Comment: You want an additional nCr ("from n choice r") or as said in Germany "n over k" algorithm to calculate the parameter to the function? Ah no, that would be 5*6*...*15

Comment: Just wrap the code that calculate the result for a single number in a loop that starts from L and end at R

Comment: Yes, that works, could be a suboptimal way. Ok, I'll put it in a simple loop at first...

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I didn't get you. the end result which i am looking for should take 2 numbers L and R.  if i give L = 5 and R = 15, then function should calculate F(5) + F(6) + F(7) ... + F(15) and return this. F in your code is sumXorSubStr

Comment: @AyoubFalah But the problem is  L, R can range from 1 to 1000000000 and that would take lot of time if R - L is more then 1000000 Thats why i am looking for a better approach to this problem. Kind of some pattern? Maybe some recurrence relation. The only observation i could find is the F(x) ranges from 1 to 120.

Comment: @AlexWho Try to follow a scientific approach. One try first to find a solution, stady the solution concerning time and space (run time and memory), then improve the initial implementation based on the results of the stadies. So you could systematically achieve your target